# GA4: Data API Data disappearing for large date ranges

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to get data of users and average session duration for specific hostName which can change for every site that is deployed on our subdomain. I used the below request but issue is if a increase date range for one month the data that I was able to see in weekly date range now disappears and its not showing data for all dates when a larger date range is selected

```
const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
                property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
                [ { startDate: '2023-10-25', endDate: '2023-11-24' } ],
                [
                {
                  name: 'hostName',
                },
                { name: 'date' }
            ],
                [
                 { name: 'activeUsers' },
                 { name: 'averageSessionDuration' },
                    ],
                dimensionFilter: {
                    filter: {
                        fieldName: 'hostName',
                        stringFilter: {
                            matchType: 'PARTIAL_REGEXP',
                            value: subdomain,
                            caseSensitive: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

I existingly had an UA property and now I have GA4 property, is it issue of data migration which I dnt think so is because I have the data on dashboard as well and when gave date range for october it also gives data for some of the days of october as well

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dashboard/statistics?subdomain=usama.com&dateFilter=monthly&sourceDomain=uyiabraham.vonza.com&startDate=2023-11-09&endDate=2023-11-26

this is the API request and its giving back data for the above date range and data is

```
`[
            {
                "date": "2023-11-09",
                "newUsers": 15,
                "sessionDuration": "1m 21s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-10",
                "newUsers": 13,
                "sessionDuration": "2m 1s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-11",
                "newUsers": 9,
                "sessionDuration": "4m 52s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-12",
                "newUsers": 6,
                "sessionDuration": "15s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-13",
                "newUsers": 19,
                "sessionDuration": "5m 17s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-14",
                "newUsers": 10,
                "sessionDuration": "3m 36s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-15",
                "newUsers": 14,
                "sessionDuration": "3m 38s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-16",
                "newUsers": 11,
                "sessionDuration": "3m 30s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-17",
                "newUsers": 4,
                "sessionDuration": "4m 45s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-18",
                "newUsers": 2,
                "sessionDuration": "1m 45s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-19",
                "newUsers": 6,
                "sessionDuration": "4m 32s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-20",
                "newUsers": 11,
                "sessionDuration": "3m 26s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-21",
                "newUsers": 27,
                "sessionDuration": "4m 14s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-22",
                "newUsers": 13,
                "sessionDuration": "2m 26s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-23",
                "newUsers": 7,
                "sessionDuration": "6m 2s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-24",
                "newUsers": 19,
                "sessionDuration": "2m 50s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-25",
                "newUsers": 13,
                "sessionDuration": "3m 28s"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-11-26",
                "newUsers": 1,
                "sessionDuration": "0s"
            }
        ]`
```

but when I change startDate to 2023-11-08 or beyond 09 everything after 089 gets 0 but it still gives data before 08

Comment: Im not sure I understand can you give me some sample data?

Comment: I have edited the question please check now